# copy or overwrite directories in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to copy or overwrite directories if they exists. Below is my directory structure

```
Dir1\workspace_template\localDB\*
```

I want to copy directory `LocalDB` to `Dir2` by preserving the folder structure.

One option is to do `cp Dir1\workspace_template\localDB Dir2 -Recurse -Force` with this if the directory exists in destination then it will create an additional `LocalDB` and copy the file there instead of overwriting.

If I do

```
if (-not (Test-Path "Dir2\workspace_template\localDB")) {
    md "Dir2\workspace_template\localDB" | Out-Null
}
cp Dir1\workspace_template\localDB\* Dir2 -Recurse -Force
```

then this will fail if any sub directories in `localDB` do not exist.
How can I copy this without creating the duplicate directories in destination?

Comment: You're looking for [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Comment: I was in the assumption that robocopy is not shipped with windows. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: `robocopy` is included with Windows since Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, you just need to put the correct path to copy to in Dir2

```
cp Dir1\workspace_template\localDB\* Dir2\workspace_template\localDB -Recurse -Force
```

This will copy the content to the same location on Dir2

Comment: This is a good and working answer, but I cannot overwhelm the feeling, it would better fit as an comment. For an answer, there is not enough description and I'm not sure if it generates a great value for future readers.

Comment: This will fail if any sub directories in localDB is missing. For EX; If `workspace_template\localDB\temp` is not present in `Dir2` it will fail.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. I created a local example with some folders with and without content in Dir1\workspace_template\localDB, when copying to Dir2\workspace_template\localDB they will be copied too.